# Nesting groovy each{} inside find{}

Tags: groovy

I know we cannot return from `.each{}` closure in groovy like `.find{}` closure. Still I am curious why the below code execute only first iteration of the `.find{}`.

```
def findlist = [1,2,3,4,5]  
def eachlist = [7,6,5]

findlist.find
{
    int findelem = it
    println "findelem : " + findelem
    eachlist.each
    {
        int eachelem = it
        println "eachelem : " + eachelem  
        if(it == findelem)
        {
            return true  
        }
        return false
    }   
}
```

It prints:

```
findelem : 1
eachelem : 7
eachelem : 6
eachelem : 5
```

Why `find{}` exits after first iteration?

PS: I understand this code might not have any practical significance, just curious about groovy behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `each` returns *unmodified* collection is iterating on. The returned collection evaluates to `true`, hence `find` stops after first iteration.

Have a look at the code below:

```
assert [1, 2].each { println it } == [1,2]

assert [1,2].find { println it; [3, 4].each { e -> println e } }
```

You need to nest `find` instead of `each`.

Comment: so `each{}` always returns the whole collection it is iterating on?

Comment: Yes, this is how it works. Please have a look at the [sources](https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DefaultGroovyMethods.java#L1889).

Answer (score 3):

Just to complete Opal's answer (each returns the collection so it evaluates to true if it is not empty), you can use a local variable inside the `find` closure to return the *found value*. Simplifying your code a bit:

```
assert 5 == findlist.find { findelem ->
    println "findelem : " + findelem
    boolean found
    eachlist.each { eachelem ->
        println "eachelem : " + eachelem  
        found = (eachelem == findelem)
    }
    found
}
```

However, there is a *nicer and groovier* way:

```
assert 5 == findlist.find { it in eachlist }
```